# How to use two WHEN elements to make field required in TFS

Tags: tfs

In VSTF 2012 I have a custom template. I have a field which uses the WHEN field element to determine if it is required based on the input from a different field - in this example the Ops Approver field is required when the Ops Required field = Operations.

```
<FieldDefinition name="Operations Approver" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.OperationsApprover" type="String" reportable="dimension">
  <VALIDUSER />
  <WHEN field="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.OpsRequired" value="Operations">
    <REQUIRED />
  </WHEN>
  </FieldDefinition>
```

This works perfectly. I now need to make this field required based on the WHEN from 2 different fields e.g. When Ops Required = Operations and Priority = 2

I have tried adding another WHEN element but they act as an OR function rather than an AND function.

I have searched on the web, on this site in MSDN and found nothing. What am I missing? Is this even possible?

Any help greatly appreciated.